Object shows wireframe in Render Preview Mode
Some Object shows wireframe in Render Preview Mode. How can I avoid this?


One edge is selected... so you're in Edit Mode. Just go back to Object Mode and the wireframe will disappear.

No I'm in Object Mode, the orange Line is the Ground selected.

Your screenshot does not show much information, so I can only give you some possible reasons for this.

You say it's Object Mode, but just for completeness: if an object is in Edit Mode, the wireframe will be visible even in Rendered shading. Here Suzanne is in Edit Mode:


Then there is the Wireframe in the Overlays. Although when this is enabled, all objects should show a wireframe:


Another possibility would be - if you are not in Edit Mode and not all objects show a wireframe - you can enable a wireframe overlay per object, if you go to the Object Properties and under Viewport Display enable Show > Wireframe:



